# How to handle an unmet peer dependency?

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

I found a new library that I want to use in my application. (ngx-translate)

When I try to install it:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
```

I get two unmet peer dependencies: `@angular/core@4.4.4` and `rxjs@5.4.3`.

My question is how I best handle this situation.

Do I simply `npm install` both of these? I am afraid that might screw something up, because in my `package.json` all angular dependencies are currently set to `^4.0.0`. They should probably all be the same version? Also, I don't quite understand how all these dependencies are `4.0.0` when the DOM of my application says it is `4.4.4`:

[image: ng-version]

Thanks.

Comment: 3 options; 1) Upgrade the unmet dependencies 2) Downgrade the installed dependency to a version whos peerDependencies are satified by your installed versions 3) YOLO; ignore the warning

Comment: And you don't think it will be a problem to only upgrade @angular/core to 4.4.4 and leave the rest of the angular stuff at 4.0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to handle unmeet peer dependencies in your case will be by doing `npm install` for both `@angular/core@4.4.4` and `rxjs@5.4.3`.
And don't worry you won't be screwing up your angular setup as `^4.0.0` allows the installation of versions up to `4.9.9`. That's why in your DOM you are seeing `angular@4.4.4`
Refer [semver](https://semver.org/) for more information on the semantics of signs like `^`, `~`, `@` etc that you can encounter in your `package.json` .
PS: Don't forget to use `--save` while installing peer dependencies.

Comment: Just want to add that according to the [semver §2](https://semver.org/#spec-item-2), *4.9.9* is not the highest version covered by `^4.0.0`: After minor version *4.9* comes **4.10** (it's just the same for the patch version).